# Making the access token request using signed JWT

Tags: google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

We got the following exception for our customers while trying to get AccessToken using signed JWT for the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly" through this protocol(https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount?hl=fr#makingrequest).

{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "Requested client not authorized."
}

It was worked earlier. We are facing this issue from last 2 days.

But we got response for Admin-SDK users API using the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly" for the same app.

Please assist me. 
TIA,
Riyaz A